# nginx deny POST to wp-login.php unless on same page

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I am noticing an uptick in remote POST commands to my wp-login.php (mostly to attempt a password reset). While I have protected against spoofing the reply address, it is still annoying that I am receiving these. So looking through the logs, I notice these requests are all remote sites sending a POST command:

`POST /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "-"`

So what I want to do is configure nginx to block any POST command that is not coming from the lost password link clicked on from the wp-login.php page itself. Is this possible?

I first tried using the following (suggested on the Wordpress site), but it does not prevent access to that page (tested in POSTMAN):

```
location ~* (wp-comments-posts|wp-login)\.php$ {
        if ($http_referer !~ ^(https://example.com) ) {
          return 405;
        }
      }
```

Then, noticing that I have another block in that file like this:

```
location = /wp-login.php {
  limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php7;
}
```

I tried to modify it in the following way:

```
location = /wp-login.php {
  limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php7;

  if ($http_referer !~ ^(https://example.com) ) {
          return 405;
        }

}
```

but this blocks EVERYONE, even in the browser, which is not what I want. Is there no way to block access to `wp-login.php?action=lostpassword` by anyone who has not come from the lost password link on wp-login.php in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Referrer is easily spoofed and generally unrealiable, don't use it for security purposes.

Instead, use a plugin to rename the URL to reach the login. Change /wp-login.php to /letMeIn/ or /MyLogin/. It's easy enough to tell your users and it keeps the random bots looking for weak passwords out completely.

I'm pretty sure that you could even put a link to your non-standard login URI on your website and still would benefit greatly from changing it, since the bots aren't analyzing your site, but just try to attack default WordPress installations.

With that out of the way,

```
if ($http_referer !~ "^https://example.org/") {  return 403; }
```

Works fine for me on a current nginx. If it does not for you, use your browser's dev tools to look at the actual requests being sent and what you're sending as the Referer to your server.

I also added a / after the hostname (even though the Header is easily forged and this won't help against forgery), to make sure it won't work for `https://example.org.example.com`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid renaming the login pages, but I have concluded you are correct, and I went that route. Thanks!